# Nearest Neighbour difference in Numpy/PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I need a to write a custom loss function in PyTorch but owing to PyTorch's similarity to NumPy, a Numpy based solution will also work.

I have two tensors(Numpy arrays) `p` and `q` of shape `(b,...)`. For each batch element in `p` I wish to compute the minimum difference w.r.t any of the batch element of `q`. Sample code is given below:

```
loss = 0
for outer in range(b):
   tmp_min = 1e+5
   for inner in range(b):
      tmp_loss = torch.abs(p[outer,...] - q[inner,...]) # np.abs(p[outer,...] - q[inner,...])
      if tmp_loss<tmp_min:
          tmp_min = tmp_loss
   loss = loss + tmp_min
```

Since I will have to compute this loss many many times, is there a way to do it without FOR and IF statements?

Finally, I wish to compute this loss in both directions. So, is there any alternative other than repeating the above code with `p` and `q` swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a singleton dimension to `p` to leverage broadcasting when doing `p-q`: `(p[:, None, ...] - q[:, ...]).shape == (B, B, ...)`.

It would work as follows:

```py
def loss_vec(p, q):
    B = p.shape[0]
    assert q.shape[0] == B
    p = p.reshape(B, -1)
    q = q.reshape(B, -1)
    return (p[:, None, :] - q).abs().sum(axis=-1).min(axis=-1).values.sum()

def loss_op(p, q):
    """OP solution as oneliner"""
    return torch.tensor([min([torch.abs(x - y).sum() for y in q]) for x in p]).sum()


B, K, M, N = 11, 3, 5, 7
p = torch.rand(B, K, M, N)
q = torch.rand(B, K, M, N)

value_op_pq = loss_op(p, q)
value_vec_pq = loss_vec(p, q)

assert value_op_pq == value_vec_pq
```

To compute in both directions, just change the `axis=...` when computing the `min`:

```py
def loss_vec_bi(p, q):
    """Returns the loss in both directions"""
    B = p.shape[0]
    assert q.shape[0] == B
    p = p.reshape(B, -1)
    q = q.reshape(B, -1)
    losses = (p[:, None, :] - q).abs().sum(axis=-1)
    return losses.min(axis=-1).values.sum(), losses.min(axis=0).values.sum()


value_op_qp = loss_op(q, p)
value_vec_pq, value_vec_qp = loss_vec_bi(p, q)

assert value_op_pq == value_vec_pq
assert value_op_qp == value_vec_qp
```